# How to count the number of true element in a bool list?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I can write a function like this

```
(define (bool-num x) (if x 1 0))
(define (cnt-true lst)
  (foldl + 0 (map bool-num lst)))
```

But I found is not elegant, because racket has a `count` function and `false?`, but there's no `true?`

So I can count the number of false element:

```
(count false? lst)
```

Anything I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the procedure `identity`:

```
(count identity '(#t #f #t #t #f))
=> 3

(count identity '(1 2 #t #f #f 9))
=> 4
```